# Convert Inkscape drawings to TikZ code

Tags: tikz-pgf, inkscape

I am trying to use Inkscape to convert drawings to TikZ code, but I am having some trouble and I don’t know how to solve it. I hope to receive help from everyone. Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: Not too sure, but you can likely click the `[...]` button to the right of "Output filename: tikzbook" and select where you want to store the generated file.